how to show picture ini print datable
i want to make my export in data table showing picture, when i press print button its always not showing picture
enter image description here
i tried modified my print js button but it didnt work
Is there a problem with my datatable, or is there something wrong with my export? I searched on YouTube but the option to print that displays photos only uses fpdf

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#kleper').length) {
        $('#kleper').DataTable();
    }

    if ($('#data-tables').length) {
        $setting = $('#dataTables-setting');
        settings = {};
        if ($setting.length > 0) {
            settings = $.parseJSON($('#dataTables-setting').html());
        }

        addSettings = {
            // "dom":"Bfrtip",
            "buttons":[
                {"extend":"copy"
                    ,"text":"<i class='far fa-copy'></i> Copy"
                    ,"className":"btn-light me-1"
                },
                {"extend":"excel"
                    , "title":"Outstanding Work Order"
                    , "text":"<i class='far fa-file-excel'></i> Excel"
                    , "exportOptions": {
                      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19],
                      modifier: {selected: null}
                    }
                    , "className":"btn-light me-1"
                },
                {"extend":"pdf"
                    ,"title":"Outstanding Work Order"
                    ,"text":"<i class='far fa-file-pdf'></i> PDF"
                    , "exportOptions": {
                      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19],
                      modifier: {selected: null}
                    }
                    ,"className":"btn-light me-1"
                },
                {"extend":"csv"
                    ,"title":"Outstanding Work Order"
                    ,"text":"<i class='far fa-file-alt'></i> CSV"
                    , "exportOptions": {
                      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19],
                      modifier: {selected: null}
                    }
                    ,"className":"btn-light me-1"
                },
                {
    extend: "print",
    title: "Outstanding Work Order",
    text: "<i class='fas fa-print'></i> Print",
    exportOptions: {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,17, 19],
        modifier: {selected: null}
    },
    className: "btn-light",
    customize: function (win) {
        $(win.document.body).find('img').each(function () {
            // Setel lebar gambar agar sesuai dengan cetakan
            $(this).css('width', '100%');
            $(this).css('height', 'auto');
        });
    }
}

                
            ],

            "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 100], // Show entries options
            "lengthChange": true, // Enable Show entries dropdown
        }

        // Merge settings
        settings['lengthChange'] = false;
        settings = { ...settings, ...addSettings };

        var table = $('#data-tables').DataTable(settings);
        table.buttons().container().appendTo('#data-tables_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');

        // No urut
        table.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
            table.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
            });
        }).draw();
    }
});


always not showing my picture
enter image description here

FYI, many web browsers will , by default , remove background colors and images when the screen is printed. . However, you may change your browser settings to force print the images if you wish
